# Rails belongs_to relationship if meets certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I have a rails app in which students can apply to projects posted by employers.  I have it so a Student has_many projects, and a Project belongs_to Student.  The problem is that the project can exist for a long time before a student is chosen for it.  What I mean by this is that until an employer presses the hire button in a view, the student_id of project is nil.  Once the employer presses the 'hire' button, I am trying to set the student_id of project to the student who was hired.  For some reason, I can't do this.  Here is the Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :student
      belongs_to :employer
      has_many :relationships

    def change_it
        self.student_id = self.relationships.where(:state => :active).first.student_id
        self.relationships.each do |relationship|
          if relationship.state != :active
            relationship.deny_applicants
          end
        end
    end
end
```

When I click the hire button, it takes me to the next page as normal, but when i check the project's student_id in the console, it is still nil.

How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to introduce an additional model to capture the relationship between the Student and the Project.  Maybe restating the problem will help clarify this.

- A Professor can create a Project at any time
- A Student can apply for a Project at any time after it has been posted
- A Professor must approve a Student's assignment to a Project

The first point suggests that the Project belongs to a Professor (not a Student).  From the second and third points I would tend to say that a Student has an Assignment to the Project and that Assignment might have 'applied', 'approved', and 'declined' states.  With that in mind I'd probably model it this way (with the state_machine gem):

```
class Student < ARec
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :approved_assignments, class_name: 'Assignment', conditions: { state: 'approved' }
end

class Project < ARec
  has_many :assignments
  has_one  :approved_assignment, class_name: 'Assignment', conditions: { state: 'approved' }
end

class Assignment < ARec
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :project

  state_machine :state, initial: :applied do
    state: :approved
    state: :declined

    event :approve do
      transition all => :approved
    end

    event :decline do
      transition all => :declined
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm actually already using the state machine gem with projects.  I think you hit on what I'm trying to do, just without the added relationship.  What I have now is that a project is initially at state 'posting.  When a student is hired, it changes to state 'actual_job'.  What I want is for when it changes to state 'actual_job', for the student_id to become associated with the correct student.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked relationships -- it's basically the same as the Assignment that I proposed.  How are you invoking Project#change_it?

Comment: I use this: ' after_transition :posting => :actual_job, :do => :change_it ' .  I know its getting invoked because deny_applicants works.

Answer (score 0):

You have the associations set up correctly.

If the error is occurring in Project#change_it, then I suspect

```
self.relationships.where(:state => :active).first
```

isn't returning a relationship.

Comment: I don't see how that can be.  Your comment did get me to rethink the question, so I updated the content with more information.

Comment: You don't show us the code that creates the relationship and assigns the student_id and project_id to the relationship. When is that happening in the workflow you described?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  Just setting a new value for student_id wasn't updating the database.  I needed to use update_attributes like this:

```
def change_it
    self.update_attributes(student_id: self.relationships.where(:state => :active).first.student_id)

    self.relationships.each do |relationship|
      if relationship.state != :active
        relationship.deny_applicants
      end
    end
end
```